Zoom Workplace 6.2.6 can't connect on Fedora 41
I've Zoom Workplace 6.2.6 installed manually from an RPM file downloaded from the official Zoom web site. When I try to login with my username and password it can't connect and saying: "It looks like we are unable to connect. Please check your network connection and try again". It also can't connect to an already started by someone else meeting using a URL without logging in and a similar error message is shown.

At the same time other people in the same LAN can connect and use Zoom. I also tried other network (WiFi connection to a Hotspot on my phone) with the same result.
If I run zoom from a terminal no additional messages are printed in that terminal.
$ dnf info zoom
Updating and loading repositories:
Repositories loaded.
Installed packages
Name            : zoom
Epoch           : 0
Version         : 6.2.6.2503
Release         : 1
Architecture    : x86_64
Installed size  : 681.9 MiB
Source          : zoom-6.2.6.2503-1.src.rpm
From repository : @commandline
Summary         : Zoom Cloud Meetings
URL             : https://www.zoom.us
License         : see https://www.zoom.us/
Description     : Zoom Cloud Meetings
                : Zoom brings people together to connect and get more done in a frictionless, secure video environment. Our easy, 
                : reliable, and innovative video-first solutions provide video meetings and chat, with additional options for webi
                : nars and phone service.
                :  .
                : Zoom is the leading unified communications platform and helps individuals, schools, healthcare professionals and
                :  enterprises stay connected. Visit blog.zoom.us and follow @zoom_us.
                :  .
                : By installing this app, you agree to our Terms of Service (https://zoom.us/terms) and Privacy Statement (https:/
                : /zoom.us/privacy).
Vendor          : Zoom Video Communications, Inc.

Is it a known bug/issue? Where can I download an older version of Zoom? For example 6.0.6

an old version probably won't work with Zoom's servers, so forget about that. Anyways, this is clearly a bug in the Zoom application, so you will have to talk to Zoom. Also, most people I know just simply install chromium-browser and use zoom in that browser (there's a small text "use zoom in the browser" when you try to join a meeting, instead of using the standalone zoom app).

This is the latest version. And it works in my colleague's Fedora 41, that was upgraded from Fedora 40. Mine Fedora 41 was installed from scratch.

yes, so it's a Zoom bug, which you need to take to Zoom.

Interesting that in my other computer with the same Fedora 41 and the same DE this version of Zoom works properly.

yes, please tell Zoom. We can't help with a closed-source software package that has updates very often and that seems to have a very specific bug on your platform. There's exactly one party that can fix that – zoom.

I’m voting to close this question because this cannot be solved by community consultation, but needs to be solved by the software vendor.

After reinstalling the same Fedora 41 from scratch and installing the same version of Zoom Workplace it works properly now.
I suspect that the root cause of my issue was trying an unofficial RPM of Microsoft Teams taken from https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux about a week ago. Even removing it during the issue didn't help. All other software is the same as in the previous Fedora 41 installation.
Microsoft itself stopped supporting native build of Teams for Linux, so this is a good example of why it's usually a bad idea to use unofficial builds made by unknown people.
